# Asus Bluetooth Dongle with Atheros (ath3k) chip - OpenSUSE - probe failed with error -5

Tags: opensuse, bluetooth

I'm trying to use an Asus USB Bluetooth Dongle in OpenSUSE. Unfortunately when I plug it in, dmesg gives me the following output:

```
usb 8-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 3
usb 8-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3000
usb 8-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
ath3k: probe of 8-2:1.0 failed with error -5
```

lsusb gives the following output:

```
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc.
```

The modules ath3k and bluetooth are loaded, but neither bluedevil nor the OpenSUSE bluetooth adapter tool detect the stick.

I'm using the 2.6.37.6-0.20-desktop kernel from the OpenSUSE repositories under openSUSE 11.4 32bit. The following packages are installed:

- bluedevil
- bluez
- bluez
- compat
- bluez-firmware
- bluez-gstreamer
- bluez-hcidump
- bluez-test
- gnome-bluetooth
- libbluedevil1
- libbluetooth3
- libgnome-bluetooth8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching I found out, that obviously the firmware for the ath3k chip on the dongle was missing. This was indicated by "/dev/.udev/firmware-missing/ath3k-1.fw". [In the wireless section of kernel.org](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath3k) I found a git repository that contains that missing firmware image.

After copying ath3k-1.fw to "/lib/firmware" the stick was recognized without further changes to the system.